# Scrapy spider does not iterate properly & has an If statement issue

Tags: python, for-loop, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape applicant data from a table with Scrapy. I'm having two issues:

1) I want a CSV with each applicant on each row:

```
'username': ['clickclack123'],'lsat':['170'],'gpa':['3.57']...
```

My code currently extracts all of the applicant data in one row, ignores null values, and iterates that extraction for the number of applicants on the page (100 identical rows where each row contains all of the data on the page):

```
'username': ['clickclack123','UM2014','3litersaday'...
```

2) The table contains a class of elements ('signifiers') which indicate applicant traits. I want to include an If statement to check the signifier and save each trait as True if applicable. I've included an If statement with this logic in lawschool.py (below), but it doesn't allow my spider to run.

My thoughts & attempts:

- For Issue #1, I've seen posts with similar issues, but those solutions haven't worked in this case because my data contains null values which I do not want ignored.
- I believe there's an issue with my For loop because it isn't iterating properly over each applicant, but I haven't been able to fix it. It currently extracts all of the data on the page into one row of my CSV, but iterates that extraction for the number of applicants on the page (100 identical rows where each row contains all of the data on the page). If I change extract() to extract_first(), the spider will only extract the data for the first applicant (100 identical rows where each row contains the data from the first applicant).
- For Issue #2, I'm not sure why my code doesn't run with this If statement and I've had to comment it out to troubleshoot Issue #1.

lawschool.py

```
import scrapy
from ..items import ApplicantItem

class LawschoolSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "lawschool"
    start_urls = [
        'http://nyu.lawschoolnumbers.com/applicants',
        'http://columbia.lawschoolnumbers.com/applicants'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        items = []
        for applicant in response.xpath("//tr[@class='row']"):
            signifier = response.xpath("//span[@class='signifier']/text()").extract()
            if signifier == 'W':
                withdrawn = True
            elif signifier == 'A':
                accepted == True
            elif signifier == 'U':
                minority == True
            elif signifier == 'N':
                non_traditional == True
            elif signifier == 'I':
                international = True
            else:
                return False
            school = response.xpath("//h1/text()").extract()
            school = [i.replace(' Applicants','') for i in school]
            item = ApplicantItem(
                school = school,
                username = response.xpath("//td/a/text()").extract(),
                lsat = response.xpath("//td[contains(@style, 'font-weight:bold')]/following-sibling::td[1]/text()").extract(),
                gpa = response.xpath("//td[contains(@style, 'font-weight:bold')]/following-sibling::td[2]/text()").extract(),
                scholarship = response.xpath("//td[contains(@style, 'font-weight:bold')]/following-sibling::td[4]/text()").extract(),
                status = response.xpath("//td[contains(@style, 'font-weight:bold')]/following-sibling::td[5]/text()").extract(),
                sent = response.xpath("//td[contains(@style, 'font-weight:bold')]/following-sibling::td[6]/text()").extract(),
                complete = response.xpath("//td[contains(@style, 'font-weight:bold')]/following-sibling::td[7]/text()").extract(),
                decision = response.xpath("//td[contains(@style, 'font-weight:bold')]/following-sibling::td[8]/text()").extract(),
                last_updated = response.xpath("//td[contains(@style, 'font-weight:bold')]/following-sibling::td[9]/text()").extract()
                withdrawn_application = withdrawn,
                accepted_offer = accepted,
                minority = minority,
                non_traditional = non_traditional,
                international = international
            )
            yield item

        for a in response.xpath("//*[@id='applicants_list']/div/a[9]"):
            yield response.follow(a, callback=self.parse)
```

items.py

```
from scrapy import Item, Field


class ApplicantItem(Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    school = Field()
    username = Field()
    lsat = Field()
    gpa = Field()
    scholarship = Field()
    status = Field()
    sent = Field()
    complete = Field()
    decision = Field()
    last_updated = Field()
    withdrawn_application = Field()
    accepted_offer = Field()
    minority = Field()
    non_traditional = Field()
    international = Field()
```

pipeline.py

```
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.exporters import CsvItemExporter

from .items import ApplicantItem

class LSNPipeline(object):

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        pipeline = cls()
        crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_opened, signals.spider_opened)
        crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
        return pipeline

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        item_names = ['applicant']
        self.files = self.files = {n: open('%s.csv' % n, 'w+b') for n in item_names}
        self.exporters = {n: CsvItemExporter(f) for n, f in self.files.items()}
        for exporter in self.exporters.values():
            exporter.start_exporting()

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        for exporter in self.exporters.values():
            exporter.finish_exporting()

        for file in self.files.values():
            file.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if isinstance(item, ApplicantItem):
            self.exporters['applicant'].export_item(item)

        return item
```

Answer (score 0):

You need *relative* XPath expressions:

```
username = applicant.xpath(".//td/a/text()").extract(),
lsat = applicant.xpath(".//td[2]/text()").extract(),
gpa = applicant.xpath(".//td[3]/text()").extract(),
...
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look! I tried that, but still have the same issue. Do you know how I can adjust the code to properly iterate?